# How to consume ActiveMQ Artemis jms topic from another application Java

Tags: java, activemq-artemis, jms-topic

I have a situation where if i call my consumer on the fly from within the app it works with the code below. How do i receive this message from a different application? Working code below:

```
public class TopicExample {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection connection = null;
        InitialContext initialContext = null;
        try {
            initialContext = new InitialContext();
            Topic topic = (Topic) initialContext.lookup("topic/exampleTopic");
            ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
            connection = cf.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);
            MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(topic);
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("This is a text message ");
            producer.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message: " + message.getText());
            connection.start();
            System.out.println("*************************************************************");
            TextMessage messageReceived = (TextMessage) messageConsumer.receive(1000);
            System.out.println("messageConsumer received: " + messageReceived.getText());
            messageConsumer.close();
        } finally {
            if (initialContext != null) {
                initialContext.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the same artemis broker and if i check the console the consumer and producer show but the message is always null with **TextMessage messageReceived = (TextMessage) messageConsumer.receive(1000);** and if i use **MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(topic);** it never goes there. My code in the different app which does not work is as below:

```
public class ExampleSubscriber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        InitialContext initialContext = null;
        try {
            initialContext = new InitialContext();
            Topic topic = (Topic) initialContext.lookup("topic/exampleTopic");
            ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
            connection = cf.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(topic);
           // messageConsumer.setMessageListener(new DefaultMessageListener()); does not work
           // TextMessage messageReceived = (TextMessage) messageConsumer.receive(1000); 
           // System.out.println(messageReceived); if i dont use listener this is always null
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (initialContext != null) {
                try {
                    initialContext.close();
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static class DefaultMessageListener implements MessageListener {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            System.out.println(message); //never comes here when using listener
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you remove the consumer from your other app, or is it still listening on that other one?  Open your Artemis MQ Client and see how many *Consumers* are registered on that topic to confirm.

Comment: No i have a consumer on the other app. If i add a thread.sleep i see the producer and consumer in the ActiveMQ Artemis management console using the default http://localhost:8161/console/ but no messages are exchanged. Something may be wrong with my code?

Comment: If you've updated your `ExampleSubscriber` to invoke `connection.start()` then you should update your question. Otherwise anybody who knows how to use JMS will think that's the problem.

Comment: Was it necessary to update? It did not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

The consumer app needs to [starts](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#start--) the JMS connection to receive incoming messages, i.e.

```
connection.start();
```

Comment: no luck I have a connection.start() in the producer and i added again in consumer but nothing changed

Comment: Is the consumer actively listening before producer sends its messages?

Comment: I do not think the order matters a lot because the subscriber will keep running until the message is received. So if I run after the producer, the message will not come at first. But should come on the second run of the producer since the consumer will still be running. Thanks anyway i managed to get it work after refactoring my code

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that messages are sent to the JMS topic *while* the consumer is actively listening for messages. As defined by the JMS specification, JMS topic consumers *only* get messages sent to the topic while they are connected. The only exception to this is if the consumer has already created a durable subscription, but you aren't doing that.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone, I tried all your suggestions but for some strange reason it did not work. After a full 2 nights of research It only worked when I used jms 2.0 implementation

```
    try (ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
         JMSContext jmsContext = cf.createContext()) {
    //add your consumer code here for consumer
    //add your producer code here for producer
    }
```